# In python, what is the fastest way to determine if a string is an email or an integer?

Tags: python, string, integer

I'd like to be able to pull users from a database using either a supplied e-mail address or the user id (an integer).  To do this, I have to detect if the supplied string is an integer, or an e-mail.  Looking for the fastest way to do this.  Thanks.

```
def __init__(self, data):
    #populate class data
    self._fetchInfo(data)


def _fetchInfo(self, data):
    #If an email
        #SELECT ... WHERE email = 'data'
    #or if a user_id
        #SELECT ... WHERE id = 'data'

    #Fill class attributes 
    self._id = row['id']
    self._email = row['id']
    ...
```

Comment: use regexp http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re-syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical way to handle this in Python is to try first, ask forgiveness later:

```
def _fetchInfo(self, data):
    try:
        data=int(data)
        sql='SELECT ... WHERE id = %s'
        args=[data]
    except ValueError:
        sql='SELECT ... WHERE email = %s'
        args=[data]
        # This might fail, in which case, data was neither a valid integer or email address
```

This strategy also goes by the moniker ["It is Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions).

Comment: hahaha.. that's how try and catch should be taught in all schools

Comment: Make sure you validate input before you just put any string into a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) function:

```
if isinstance(data, int):
   # it's an id
else:
   # it's a string
```

Though personally, I'd just have two methods, `fetchById` and `fetchByEmail` to make it clear that's how it works.

Comment: isinstance won't work, since: "I have to detect if the supplied **string** ..." - it will always be an instance of str.

Comment: Oh yes, I see that now... in that case, ~unutbu's answer will still work.

Answer (score 2):

You said both were strings, right?  This would work, too.

```
if data.isdigit():
    # it's an id
else:
    # it's not
```

Comment: @dan04.
True, but auto-incrementing db id's generally aren't negative.

Answer (score 1):

```
if '@' in data:
    # email
else:
    # id
```